# Amazon API Gateway Custom Header

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, http-headers, aws-api-gateway

I've created an API with Amazon Gateway but the problem is that, when I deploy it, it becomes open to the public, so I would like to create a custom header so that I can actually call the API this way

```
curl -X GET -H "X-custom-header" "amazon_api_gateway_url?some_param"
```

In order to do that, I've created a GET resource for my API and then in **Method Request** I've added a HTTP-request Header (i.e. `X-custom-header`). However, after I deploy the API and try to curl it I get a `{"message":"Forbidden"}` error.

Have you ever come across this error with this setting?

Comment: Is your goal to secure your API from the outside world? If so, what is about to use the built-in API keys of API Gateway?

Comment: Yep, using an API Key is another option as well. I found a way to set it up, but I'm not sure how to actually add the API keys in the request

Comment: Its well documented. Take a look to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-api-keys.html)